# how to render another page inside my submenu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created menu for my plugin page like follow..

```
function createMenu() {
    add_menu_page('Configuration Contact Page', 'Conatct US Setting', 'manage_options', 'adminmenu', 'welcome');
    add_submenu_page("adminmenu","Form Setting", "Form Setting", "manage_options", 'formbuilder', 'formbuilder');
}
```

now my question is how can render form.php when I click on Form Setting page. in form.php I have html code.

my function is

```
function formbuilder() {
    //how to render form.php here
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include file into your function

```
function formbuilder() {
    // to render form.php here
    include('form.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just echo your content

```
function formbuilder()
{
  echo '<form>hello, I am a form</form>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [locate_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) function to find out where the needed template is, then include it.

```
function formbuilder()
{
    include locate_template('form.php');
}
```